# saving various 2D matrices into a 3D matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I am trying to save various 2D matrices from python into a 3D matrix, but I'm receiving an error, here are the matrices:

```
rho=np.zeros((Nx,Nt))
p=np.zeros((Nx,Nt))
u=np.zeros((Nx,Nt))
U=np.zeros((Nx,Nt,3))
F=np.zeros((Nx,Nt,3))
```

I'm trying to save combinations of the first three into the last two like this:

```
F[:][:][0]=u*rho
F[:][:][1]=p*u**2+p
F[:][:][2]=u(e + p)
```

know that e is another NX by Nt matrix in another part of the code, it seems I'm not assigning this properly as I get an error saying I can't save a 1000*1000 matrix into a 1000*3 matrix, which is understandable, but of course my idea is to save the 1000*1000 matrix into the first "element" of my 3d matrix F and other combinations into my U matrix and so on, can anyone tell me how to do this, saving the 2d matrices into indexes of 3d matrices, I also tried with `U[0][:][:]=rho`

Comment: Try : `F[:,:,0]` instead of `F[:][:][0]` and so on. [`Docs on indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) might help on this and in the long run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Divakar pointed out, I wasn't using indexes correctly, using `F[:,:,0]=u*rho`etc, corrected the problem.